# python learning tkinter listbox catch no selection error

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

Coming from vba (I know it's not the best language to do things) but I am surprised I can't easily control a list box form in tkinter when no selection is made (very easy to do in a vba listform)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class Application(Frame):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.create_widgets()

def create_widgets(self):
    self.master.title("Application")
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

    Label(self, text="First Name").grid(row=0,column=0)
    self.e1 = Entry(self)
    self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    Label(self, text="Last Name").grid(row=1,column=0)
    self.e2 = Entry(self)
    self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
    Label(self, text="Age").grid(row=2, column=0)
    self.e3 = Entry(self)
    self.e3.grid(row=2, column=1)

    #Blank
    Label(self, text="").grid(row=2, column=0)

    Label(self, text="Gender").grid(row=0, column=4)
    self.f1=Frame(self, relief="sunken", borderwidth = 1)
    self.v=IntVar()

    self.r1=Radiobutton(self.f1, text="Male", variable=self.v, value=1).pack(anchor=W)
    self.r2=Radiobutton(self.f1, text="Female", variable=self.v, value=2).pack(anchor=W)
    self.f1.grid(row=1, column=4)

    Label(self, text="").grid(row=3)

    #Course Applied For
    Label(self, text="Course Applied for:", wraplength=60).grid(row=4)

    self.L1 = Listbox(self, width = 25, height = 4)

    Courses = [
    "Quality Management (Adv.)",
    "Financial Management (Adv.)",
    "Project Management (Adv.)",
    "Project Management (Int.)"
    ]

    for idx, item in enumerate(Courses):
        self.L1.insert(END, item)

    self.L1.grid(row=4, column=1)

    #Buttons
    self.f2=Frame(self)
    self.w=Button(self.f2, text ="Prerequisites", width=10, command=self.Chk_Prereq, default=ACTIVE).pack()
    self.w1=Button(self.f2, text ="Clear",  width=10, command=self.Clear).pack()
    self.w2=Button(self.f2, text ="Cancel", width=10, command=self.quit).pack()
    self.f2.grid(row=4, column=4)
    #Blank
    Label(self, text="").grid(row=6)
    #Checkbox
    self.var=IntVar()
    self.c=Checkbutton(self, text="Part-Time Course", variable=self.var, offvalue=0, onvalue=1)
    self.c.grid(row=7, column=0)


def Chk_Prereq(self):
    self.Eval()

def Eval(self):
    self.fname = self.e1.get()
    self.lname = self.e2.get()
    self.age = int(self.e3.get())
    #Check for Age
    if self.age < 21:
        messagebox.showwarning("Invalid Age",\
        "You are not eligible")
        return
    #Check for Gender
    if self.v.get()==1:
        self.str1 = "Dear Mr."
    elif self.v.get()==2:
        self.str1 = "Dear Ms."
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Missing Info", \
        "Please select the appropriate gender")
        return
    #Check for Prereq Course
    self.name = self.str1 + " " + self.fname + " " + self.lname
    self.varl1 = self.L1.get(self.L1.curselection())

    #if any(self.varl1.)

    if self.varl1 == "Quality Management (Adv.)":
        self.prereq = "The prereq for this course is Quality Management (Int)."
        self.flag = 1
    elif self.varl1 == "Financial Management (Adv.)":
        self.prereq = \
    "The prereq for this course is Financial Management (Bas)."
        self.flag = 1
    elif self.varl1 == "Project Management (Adv.)":
        self.prereq = \
    "The prereq for this course is Project Management (Int)."
        self.flag = 0
    #add1
    elif self.varl1 == "Project Management (Int.)":
        self.prereq = \
    "The prereq for this course is Project Management (Bas)."
        self.flag = 0
    #add11
    else:
        self.prereq = \
        "Please make a selection"
        self.flag = 0
    #Check whether Part Time
    if self.var.get() == 1 and self.flag == 0:
        self.str2 = "\nThis course is not available part time."
    elif self.var.get() == 1 and self.flag == 1:
        self.str2 = "\nThis course is available part time."
    else:
        self.str2 = ""
        self.result = self.prereq + self.str2
        messagebox.showinfo(self.name, self.result)

def Clear(self):
    self.e1.delete(0,END)
    self.e2.delete(0,END)
    self.e3.delete(0,END)
    self.c.deselect()
    self.L1.select_clear(self.L1.curselection())

def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Application()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It works fine

It's a script from a [python2 ebook](http://160592857366.free.fr/joe/ebooks/tech/Wiley%20Making%20Use%20of%20Python.pdf) with a few changes.

The thing is that when no selection is made in the course listbox, I get a error messages in the console window as:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/ananas/Documents/python scripts/py---2--tuto-tkinter/tuto_tk700.py", line 71, in Chk_Prereq
    self.Eval()
  File "/home/ananas/Documents/python scripts/py---2--tuto-tkinter/tuto_tk700.py", line 93, in Eval
    self.varl1 = self.L1.get(self.L1.curselection())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3182, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get', first)
_tkinter.TclError: bad listbox index "": must be active, anchor, end, @x,y, or a number
```

The **def Eval(self) function** seems where I can catch a no listbox selection but I have tried empty string conditions and a few others things so to have **self.prereq = "Please make a selection"** but it's not getting there. Any help?

Comment: Change `self.varl1 = self.L1.get(self.L1.curselection())` to `self.varl1 = self.L1.get(self.L1.curselection()) if self.L1.curselection() else ''`.

Answer (score 1):

First: Eval is already a function in python, so maybe change the name.

Second (Line 93): If I see this correct, you try to query the selection. But without anything selected you don't get anything returned from the curselection() function.

Change

```
self.varl1 = self.L1.get(self.L1.curselection())
```

to

```
if self.L1.curselection() == ():
    #NOTHING IS SELECTED, MAYBE THROW AN ERROR
else:
    self.varl1 = self.L1.get(self.L1.curselection())
```

Edit: checked for "" but a comment told me that the function returns a tulple instead of a string

Comment: `self.L1.curselection()` returns a `tuple` so `if self.L1.curselection() == ""` will always be False.

Answer (score -1):

It's tricky because checking against each value like below doesn't work

```
def Chk_Prereq(self):
    Courses = [
    "Quality Management (Adv.)",
    "Financial Management (Adv.)",
    "Project Management (Adv.)",
    "Project Management (Int.)"
    ]

    boo = 1

    self.varl1 = self.L1.get(self.L1.curselection())
    for idx, item in enumerate(Courses):
        if self.varl1 != item:
            boo = 0
        else:
            boo = 1

    if boo == 1:
        self.EvalInput()
    else: messagebox.showwarning("Course selection missing")
```

checking against the variable type like below also fails

```
isinstance(self.L1.get(self.L1.curselection()), str)
```

So I went on with the handling exception which I think is quite common in Python and not much in vba because vba is more flexible for this situation. I would be able to see what the listbox selection refers to exactly in memory as data type. Python throws a message in the console window that doesn't give much information and would leave the user wondering what is missing for a form with more entries...

Using handling exceptions is perillous to me because if something else I can't see is inside or outside that block, it would take hours before I get to see where it is. As I am somehow starting learning, I (think) Iwould understand better later (time will tell). The code I got into for illustration.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
    
class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        #Label(master, text="First Name").grid(row=0)
        self.master.title("Application")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        Label(self, text="First Name").grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.e1 = Entry(self)
        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        Label(self, text="Last Name").grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.e2 = Entry(self)
        self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        Label(self, text="Age").grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.e3 = Entry(self)
        self.e3.grid(row=2, column=1)

        #Blank
        Label(self, text="").grid(row=2, column=0)

        Label(self, text="Gender").grid(row=0, column=4)
        self.f1=Frame(self, relief="sunken", borderwidth = 1)
        self.v=IntVar()

        self.r1=Radiobutton(self.f1, text="Male", variable=self.v, value=1).pack(anchor=W)
        self.r2=Radiobutton(self.f1, text="Female", variable=self.v, value=2).pack(anchor=W)
        self.f1.grid(row=1, column=4)

        Label(self, text="").grid(row=3)

        #Course Applied For
        Label(self, text="Course Applied for:", wraplength=60).grid(row=4)

        self.L1 = Listbox(self, width = 25, height = 4)

        Courses = [
        "Quality Management (Adv.)",
        "Financial Management (Adv.)",
        "Project Management (Adv.)",
        "Project Management (Int.)"
        ]

        for idx, item in enumerate(Courses):
            self.L1.insert(END, item)

        self.L1.grid(row=4, column=1)

        #Buttons
        self.f2=Frame(self)
        self.w=Button(self.f2, text ="Prerequisites", width=10, command=self.Chk_Prereq, default=ACTIVE).pack()
        self.w1=Button(self.f2, text ="Clear",  width=10, command=self.Clear).pack()
        self.w2=Button(self.f2, text ="Cancel", width=10, command=self.quit).pack()
        self.f2.grid(row=4, column=4)
        #Blank
        Label(self, text="").grid(row=6)
        #Checkbox
        self.var=IntVar()
        self.c=Checkbutton(self, text="Part-Time Course", variable=self.var, offvalue=0, onvalue=1)
        self.c.grid(row=7, column=0)


def Chk_Prereq(self):
    self.EvalInput()

def EvalInput(self):
    self.fname = self.e1.get()
    self.lname = self.e2.get()
    self.age = int(self.e3.get())
    #Check for Age
    if self.age < 21:
        messagebox.showwarning("Invalid Age",\
        "You are not eligible")
        return
    #Check for Gender
    if self.v.get()==1:
        self.str1 = "Dear Mr."
    elif self.v.get()==2:
        self.str1 = "Dear Ms."
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("Missing Info", \
        "Please select the appropriate gender")
        return
    #Check for Prereq Course
    self.name = self.str1 + " " + self.fname + " " + self.lname

    try:
        self.varl1 = self.L1.get(self.L1.curselection())

        if self.varl1 == "Quality Management (Adv.)":
            self.prereq = "The prereq for this course is Quality Management (Int)."
            self.flag = 1
        elif self.varl1 == "Financial Management (Adv.)":
            self.prereq = \
        "The prereq for this course is Financial Management (Bas)."
            self.flag = 1
        elif self.varl1 == "Project Management (Adv.)":
            self.prereq = \
        "The prereq for this course is Project Management (Int)."
            self.flag = 0
        else:
            self.prereq = \
            "The prereq for this course is Project Management (Bas)."
            self.flag = 0
        #Check whether Part Time
        if self.var.get() == 1 and self.flag == 0:
            self.str2 = "\nThis course is not available part time."
        elif self.var.get() == 1 and self.flag == 1:
            self.str2 = "\nThis course is available part time."
        else:
            self.str2 = ""
            self.result = self.prereq + self.str2
            messagebox.showinfo(self.name, self.result)

    except:
        self.prereq = "No course selection made"
        self.result = self.prereq
        messagebox.showinfo(self.name, self.result)

def Clear(self):
    self.e1.delete(0,END)
    self.e2.delete(0,END)
    self.e3.delete(0,END)
    self.c.deselect()
    self.L1.select_clear(self.L1.curselection())



def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Application()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks for above comments but I come to think that handling exceptions is the only answer to this. Please post the whole code if that's not the case for futur use of tk listbox that might be helpful, I'll mark it as answer and upvote